# Pulling text from html element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Express, and have some products added to the page with a `for..in` loop.

```
          <div class="row" id="productList">
            <% for(let item in product) { %>
              <div class="card">
                <img src="<%= product[item].image %>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <h3 class="card-title">
                  <%= product[item].name %>
                </h3>
                <p class="card-text">
                  <%= product[item].description %>
                </p>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <p>
                    <%= product[item].price_cents %>
                  </p>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus add-burg-event"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <% } %>
          </div>
```

These products have titles in the `<h3 class=card-title>` that I would like to use. With jQuery, I am pulling the closest card, which contains all the needed data, since I will eventually need the description and displayed price too.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.add-burg-event').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.closest('.card'));
  });
});
```

So far so good. My issue is that the console.log above is printing the the following:

```
<div class=“card”>
      <img src=“images/01_CheeseBurger.jpeg” class=“card-img-top” alt=“...“>
      <h3 class=“card-title”>
        Cheese Burger
      </h3>
      <p class=“card-text”>
        Angus Beef, Letuce, Tomato, Cheese
      </p>
      <div class=“card-footer”>
      <p>
        600
      </p>
      <a href=“#”><i class=“fas fa-cart-plus add-burg-event”></i></a>
     </div>
  </div>
```

How can I access or extract the `<h3>` contents of `Cheese Burger` so I can save it into a variable, instead of the entire parent element? I tried a few things with .contents, .text, and .find, but haven't been successful yet. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting to the `.card`, navigate to the descendant heading first:

```
$('.add-burg-event').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const h3 = $(this).closest('.card').find('.card-title');
  console.log(h3.text());
});
```

Remember to surround `this` with `$` so that you can use jQuery methods - if you just do `this.closest(...)`, you're working with native DOM elements and methods instead of with jQuery. (They both  have a `.closest` method)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this differently and use HTML5 `data-attributes` to store the data points on the clickable items itself - that way on the click - you do not need to access the parent .card to parse the text for the information

Note the added data attributes on the `<a>` element - incidentally - I would probably use a `<button>` element for that - since you are not navigating anywhere and you are using the event.preventDefault() method to prevent the normal action of the a element. I also moved the class onto the button since that is what the clcick hander should be on - not the icon within the button.

```
      <div class="row" id="productList">
        <% for(let item in product) { %>
          <div class="card">
            <img src="<%= product[item].image %>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <h3 class="card-title">
              <%= product[item].name %>
            </h3>
            <p class="card-text">
              <%= product[item].description %>
            </p>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <p>
                <%= product[item].price_cents %>
              </p>
              <button 
                class="add-burg-event"
                data-name="<%= product[item].name %>"
                data-description="<%= product[item].description%>"
                data-price="<%= product[item].price%>"
              >
                 <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <% } %>
      </div>
```

This will compile to the following

```
<div class=“card”>
      <img src=“images/01_CheeseBurger.jpeg” class=“card-img-top” alt=“...“>
      <h3 class=“card-title”>
        Cheese Burger
      </h3>
      <p class=“card-text”>
        Angus Beef, Letuce, Tomato, Cheese
      </p>
      <div class=“card-footer”>
      <p>
        600
      </p>
      <button 
         class="add-burg-event"
         data-name ="Cheese Burger"
         data-description="Angus Beef, Letuce, Tomato, Cheese"
         data-price="600"
       >
         <i class=“fas fa-cart-plus”></i>
       </button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Then on the click event - you already have all required information without any messy DOM parsing / interaction

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.add-burg-event').on('click', function() {
    const name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    const description= $(this).attr('data-description');
    const price= $(this).attr('data-price');
    console.log(name); // will give "Cheese Burger"
  });
});
```